# f:ajax doesn't work when parameters are passed using f:param

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I am calling a method on the click of link. The following code works ajaxfully

```
                        <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.names}" var="name"
                               varStatus="idx">
                        <li>
                            <h:commandLink value="#{name.label}">
                                <f:ajax execute="@this" event="click" render="@all" listener="#{myBean.changeActiveName}" >
                                </f:ajax>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </li>
                    </ui:repeat>
```

But when I try to pass parameter to the Ajax call it starts refreshing the whole page

```
                    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.names}" var="name"
                               varStatus="idx">
                        <li>
                            <h:commandLink value="#{name.label}">
                                <f:ajax execute="@this" event="click" render="@all" listener="#{myBean.changeActiveName}" >
                                    <f:param name="idx" value="#{idx}" />
                                </f:ajax>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </li>
                    </ui:repeat>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<f:param>` has to be a child of the parent `UICommand` component, not of `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{name.label}">
    <f:param name="idx" value="#{idx}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.changeActiveName}" render="@all" />
</h:commandLink>
```

*(note that I removed the `execute` and `event` attributes as your definitions are the defaults already; plus I wonder how it's useful to send a whole `IterationStatus` instance as request parameter ... maybe you just wanted to send the index instead? Use `#{idx.index}` instead or so)*

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable) (although this treats `<h:dataTable>`, exactly the same answer applies to `<ui:repeat>` as well)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I got confused by some of the examples I found on stackoverflow. And yes, I have removed defaults too and now using idx.index. Thanks