# Ajax ItemSelectEvent null when using multiple parameters in listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, event-handling

I am having trouble because I have a method in Java, I need the function to receive 2 values, String and ItemSelectEvent because I use the same funciton several times.

How can I send the event from the XHTML?

Here's how I tried to do it:

```
<p:chart type="donut" model="#{bean.donut}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.createModel("P", event)}" 
         update="grap"/>
</p:chart>
```

The bean method:

```
public void createModel(String str, ItemSelectEvent event){
...
}
```

But the method always receives the "event" as null, only receives the event when I call it like this

```
<p:chart type="donut" model="#{bean.donut}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.createModel}" 
         update="grap"/>
</p:chart>
```

Bean

```
public void createModel(ItemSelectEvent event){
...
}
```

But i need it to send the extra String, thanks in advance

Comment: does it fail on another type of component to? Does it fail on plain jsf to (h:component and f:ajax) ?

Comment: Is this solution acceptable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782430/how-to-pass-additional-parameters-in-ajax-request-on-change-value-in-hselectone

Comment: this is what it sends when I try sending anything
createModel(java.lang.String, null)
how can I send the event, I tried doing org.primefaces.event.ItemSelectEvent, event, ItemSelectEvent and everything sends null, except when I send nothing, but I need to send the String with the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem, instead of

```
<p:chart type="donut" model="#{bean.donut}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.createModel("P", event)}" 
         update="grap"/>
</p:chart>
```

I did

```
<p:chart type="donut" model="#{bean.donut}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.createModel}" onStart="bean.str('T')" 
         update="grap"/>
</p:chart>
```

and on the bean I made it an attribute instead of a parameter

-----------------Edit-------------------

So I was having problems with the time of execution and what I ended up doing was call a method like this:

```
<p:ajax ... listener="#{bean.method}"/>
```

and the method was declared like this

```
method(itemSelectEvent e){
     method2("P", e);
}
method2(String option, itemSelectEvent e){
     ...
}
```

and made one method for each option I wanted to call

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the string attribute in a **f:attribute** inside **p:chart** and then catch it in your backing bean method:

```
event.getComponent().getAttributes.get("attributeName");
```